# How to create types.array in MST from external api - always returning proxy not object

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm fetching data from external API, and want to store it in MST store as array. But the result is always proxy, not the object I wanted.

This is result from API:

```
(4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
id:1
name: "Foobar"
created_at: "2019-04-27 09:09:29"
updated_at:null
deleted_at:null
__proto__:Object
.........
```

This is my store:

```
const TypesModel = types.model({
  name: types.maybe(types.string),
  created_at: types.maybe(types.string)
});

export const TransactionTypeStore = types
  .model("TransactionTypeStore", {
    transaction_types: types.optional(types.array(TypesModel), [])
  })
  .actions(self => ({
    getTypes: flow(function*(token) {
      try {
        const res = yield typesApi
          .headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
          .get()
          .json();

        console.log("result", res);

        self.transaction_types = res;

        // res.map(data => {
        //   self.transaction_types.push(data);
        // });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }));
```

And this is console.log of my MST store:

```
transaction_types:Proxy
[[Handler]]:Object
[[Target]]:Array(4)
0:ObjectNode
1:ObjectNode
2:ObjectNode
3:ObjectNode
$treenode:ObjectNode
length:4
toJSON:function toJSON()
Symbol(mobx administration):ObservableArrayAdministration
__proto__:Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]:false
.........
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: it's just mobx object, you can use `toJS` function to change it to normal object https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your `res` object look like, it should be an array of `{ name, created_at }` objects - nothing more nothing less, is it? Also `transaction_types` will never be a mere array - `types.array` is a complex MST type, it has some array methods, but it's not an array. It's [an observable array](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) and you should treat it accordingly.

Also check this video tutorial by Michel Weststrate himself: [Use observable objects, arrays, and maps to store state in MobX](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-observable-objects-arrays-and-maps-to-store-state-in-mobx) to get a better grip on the concept (*create an account, it's free*).

Answer (score 1):

its similar to TypeScript, only you are using Mobx   .MODEL

So lets say we want to create a ToDo list, which array that has  id: number, name: string, isDone: boolean.

You first Define this Interface using Mobx  .model, like this:

```
const singleToDoItem = types.model({
    id: types.number,
    name: types.string,
    isDone: types.boolean
})
```

we then create an Actual Store, with ARRAY as a type (you can also use .optional) AND then  put the  singleToDoItem inside the   types.array(singleToDoItem), so it looks like this:

```
const myStore = types.model({
    list: types.array(singleToDoItem)
})
```

FINAL CODE will look like this:

```
const singleToDoItem = types.model({
    id: types.number,
    name: types.string,
    isDone: types.boolean })

const myStore = types.model({
    toDoList: types.array(singleToDoItem) })
```

I made [a video](https://youtu.be/c44bG09iSPk) on how to do this on my YouTube channel.